# mongodb regex to find two words with exactly n or less words between them

Tags: javascript, regex, mongodb, find

i want help with a regex so that i can query mongodb in the following manner to get the following results

1. A x y B
2. A x B
3. A B

in short i want a regex which finds two words with exactly n words or less between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
/Start( \w+){0,n} end/
```

#### Example

```
/Start( \w+){0,1} end/
```

Matches

```
Start word word word end // NO MATCH
Start word word end      // NO MATCH
Start word end           // MATCH
Start end                // MATCH
```

**Edit**

You should use

```
/^Start( \w+){0,n} end$/
```

This takes better advantage of mongodb's [indexes](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#index-use) for querys and is also faster with non-indexed fields.